# ThreeJS: Text Sprite's font size difference between WebGL renderer and Canvas renderer

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, three.js

I am using Three JS to develop a 3d graph. I want to show units of a graph as `THREE.SPRITE`. For creating `SPRITE`, I have first created a canvas element and added text to it. Then I have created `THREE.Texture` with the canvas element that was previously created. Created `THREE.SpriteMaterial` with the texture as a map and then created `THREE.SPRITE` using this sprite material. Added this sprite material to scene. When the renderer is an instance of `THREE.WebGLRenderer` the size of text is very small and when the renderer is an instance of `THREE.CanvasRenderer` then the size of text is very large.

Following is the code that I have used to create Sprite.

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    metrics = null,
    textHeight = 100,
    textWidth = 0,
    actualFontSize = 20;

context.font = "normal " + textHeight + "px Arial";
metrics = context.measureText("Sample Text");
var textWidth = metrics.width;

canvas.width = textWidth;
canvas.height = textHeight;
context.font = "normal " + textHeight + "px Arial"; 
context.textAlign = "center";
context.textBaseline = "middle";
context.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
context.fillText("Sample Text", textWidth / 2, textHeight / 2);

var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
texture.needsUpdate = true;

var material = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({ map: texture, useScreenCoordinates: false, alignment: THREE.SpriteAlignment.center });
material.transparent = true;
//var textObject = new THREE.Sprite(material);
var textObject = new THREE.Object3D();
var sprite = new THREE.Sprite(material);
textObject.textHeight = actualFontSize;
textObject.textWidth = (textWidth / textHeight) * textObject.textHeight;
//sprite.scale.set(textObject.textWidth / textWidth, textObject.textHeight / textHeight, 1);
textObject.add(sprite);

scene.add(textObject);
```

Is it the default behavior or am I doing anything wrong. I am seeking a fix that works in both Canvas and WebGL renderers consistently.

Comment: Unfortunately, `WebGLRender` and `CanvasRenderer` do not scale sprites the same. This is something that should be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can I know the whether the difference in sizes is proportional/relative when scaled using CanvasRenderer and WebGLRenderer, so that I can use an if-else block and write different logic for two renderers. It is sufficient for me if text sizes are similar (and not exactly the same).

Comment: With `WebGLRenderer`, a `Sprite` having scale ( 1, 1, 1 ) should render the same size as a `PlaneGeometry` of size ( 1, 1 ) having the same location. (three.js r.62) For `CanvasRenderer`, I am not sure what the scaling logic is. Perhaps you can track it down and suggest an improvement.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for taking your time to help me. I am working on it now. If I find any fix I will suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After trying so many combinations, the following code worked.

```
var SCREEN_WIDTH = 400,
    SCREEN_HEIGHT = 300,
    VIEW_ANGLE = 45,
    ASPECT = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT,
    NEAR = 0.1,
    FAR = 20000,
    webGLScene = new THREE.Scene(),
    canvasScene = new THREE.Scene(),
    webGLCamera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR),
    canvasCamera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR),
    webGLRenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true }),
    canvasRenderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();

webGLScene.add(webGLCamera);
canvasScene.add(canvasCamera);

webGLCamera.position.set(0, 0, 20);
webGLCamera.lookAt(webGLScene.position);

canvasCamera.position.set(0, 0, 20);
canvasCamera.lookAt(canvasScene.position);

webGLRenderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
canvasRenderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

container = document.body;
container.appendChild(webGLRenderer.domElement);
container.appendChild(canvasRenderer.domElement);

makeSprite(webGLScene, "webgl");
makeSprite(canvasScene, "2d");

function makeSprite(scene, rendererType) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        metrics = null,
        textHeight = 100,
        textWidth = 0,
        actualFontSize = 2;

    context.font = "normal " + textHeight + "px Arial";
    metrics = context.measureText("Sample Text");
    var textWidth = metrics.width;

    canvas.width = textWidth;
    canvas.height = textHeight;
    context.font = "normal " + textHeight + "px Arial";
    context.textAlign = "center";
    context.textBaseline = "middle";
    context.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
    context.fillText("Sample Text", textWidth / 2, textHeight / 2);

    var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
    texture.needsUpdate = true;

    var material = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({ map: texture, useScreenCoordinates: false, alignment: THREE.SpriteAlignment.center });
    material.transparent = true;
    //var textObject = new THREE.Sprite(material);
    var textObject = new THREE.Object3D();
    var sprite = new THREE.Sprite(material);
    textObject.textHeight = actualFontSize;
    textObject.textWidth = (textWidth / textHeight) * textObject.textHeight;
    if (rendererType == "2d") {
        sprite.scale.set(textObject.textWidth / textWidth, textObject.textHeight / textHeight, 1);
    } else {
        sprite.scale.set(textWidth / textHeight * actualFontSize, actualFontSize, 1);
    }

    textObject.add(sprite);

    scene.add(textObject);
}

canvasRenderer.render(canvasScene, canvasCamera);
webGLRenderer.render(webGLScene, webGLCamera);
```

Add THREE JS (release 62) link and use the following script.

Hope this helps others with similar problems.

**Update:** Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hQ65v/1/) of the above code.

Comment: It appears that the sprite units are in pixels for the canvas2d renderer (1 pixel = 1 world unit), but the units are world units for the webgl renderer.  Hence, above, you need to scale the canvas2d height by 2/100, but the webgl renderer by 2.  Perhaps this helps someone like @WestLangley see where the inconsistency is?

Comment: This works quite well for the WebGL renderer, the only problem is that the text is pixelated. Have you had this issue to?